# cannot add two emails in to: of emailext

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to add 2nd email to my current setting but getting various while trying to add.

I tried using, ; or [] but was not able to send email to two seperate emails.

```
 emailext(
                         attachmentsPattern: "**/*_SC.sql",
                         subject: "Build ${env.JOB_NAME} - ${currentBuild.displayName} ${currentBuild.currentResult}",
                         body: """Build ${currentBuild.result}
                                    ${env.JOB_URL}
                               """,
                         to: 'email1@test.com','email2@test.com'
                     )
```

I would like to send same emails to two different emails in the process above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I define multiple addresses like so

```
to: "email1@test.com,email2@test.com"
```